# Select area code from phone number entries

Tags: mysql, database, select

I want to select only the area code from a list of column entries populated by phone numbers. This is what I have:

```
SELECT LEFT(phone, 3) AS areacode, COUNT(phone) AS count 
FROM registration 
GROUP BY areacode;
```

The problem is, the entries aren't consistent. So some phone numbers start as +123-456-7899, and others with (123)-456-7899, and others with no symbol at the beginning.

So my question is: is there a way that I can ensure the SELECT LEFT starts at the first *integer*?

Thanks!

Comment: what about numbers with international dialing codes? 1-123-456-7890?

Comment: substring(phone,2, 3) AS areacode ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are somethings that SQL is just not meant for.  This is one.  I would select the phone number into a string, and do some pattern matching in your programming language of choice to find the area code.

-OR-

Change your table such that area code is a different column.

Comment: So the best answer is that it can't be done? That's fair. Thank you for your answer; your suggestions are also good.

Comment: It can be done, but it is not what SQL is meant for.  Using a programming language such as java or php will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Two options (neither of which being SQL):

1. Select all phone numbers and use a programming language of your choice to programatically strip out the unnecessary characters.
2. Clean the input to strip out all unnecessary characters *prior* to inserting them into the database

SQL is not the best way to do this, rather, SQL + programming

Comment: Thanks @Evan for the good suggestions. Pete Bel answered a bit faster so I voted him best answer. I appreciate it anyway

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way to do this in SQL that was intentionally designed for this exact purpose.

SELECT SUBSTRING(office_phone_number, 1, 3) FROM contact;

Of course, this depends on how the number is stored in the table. If parenthesis are present, your starting position would be off.

Here is more information:
[MySQL substring function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php)